# Intervals between the last drops of liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, dirac-delta-distributions

When a bottle is nearly empty, the remaining liquid would come in the form of drops, which are becoming less and less frequent. I am wondering, if there is distribution describing the intervals between the drops (something like $t_{n+1}=\alpha t_n$ with $\alpha>1$), and whether this distribution is universal or depends on the shape of the reservoir (i e. the bottle, but one can observe the same phenomen in a water hose, after the tap is closed.)

(A simple model of this phenomenon would be appreciated.)

Comment: Probably a little different but chaotic dripping can occur from faucets due to nonlinear behavior of as the water drop separates. People would observe the chaos by recording an audio and plotting the time difference between drops. I think the last few drops case it would probably be dependent on the contact angle between the bottle material and the water. Perhaps the shape of the edge.